# Function runs double after the first activation

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, api, asynchronous

Okay so I'm working on a program that when I press a button in the getNumber function. The ArrayAPI creates an array as it fetches from an API and then base on that API it creates a bunch of divisions with a single number in it.

I was hoping to create a table.

The original div is made ".dogTable"

Then it goes through a loop. The loop first creates another div "dogRowX", then adds a

element to that div. Up to five per row before create a new row.

This works once, but for some reason every time after that the arrayAPI function runs multiple times. The 2nd time I activate getNumber(), arrayAPI() runs twice. The third time it runs 4 times. Fourth time, 8.

I have no idea why it is doubling like this.

```
function readyFunctions(){
    console.log("readyFuntions ran")
    let dogNumber = 1;
    getNumber();
}

async function getNumber(){
    console.log("getNumber ran")
    await $('.getDogs').on('click', '.puppyButton', function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        $('.dogDisplay').empty();
        console.log("Display emptied");
        dogNumber = $('.puppyNumber').val();
        console.log("dogNumber is: " + dogNumber);

        arrayAPI();
    })
}

async function arrayAPI(){
    console.log("arrayAPI ran");

    let dogPool = [];
    for (i=0; i<dogNumber; i++){
        await fetch('https://dog.ceo/api/breeds/image/random')
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(responseJSON => dogPool.push(responseJSON))
        .catch(error => alert('error! danger!'));
    }

    console.log(dogPool);
    console.log("length of dogpool: " + dogPool.length);

    $('.dogDisplay').append(
        "<div class='dogTable'></div>"
    );

    let rowNumber = 0;
    const rowLimit = 5; 

    for (i=0; i<dogPool.length; i++){
            if (i%5 == 0){
                console.log("making row " + rowNumber);
            $('.dogTable').append(
                "<div class='dogLine dogRow" + rowNumber + "'></div>"
            );

                rowName = ".dogRow" + rowNumber;
                rowNumber++;
            }
            $(rowName).append(
                "<p>"+ i + "</p>"
            );
        }


    readyFunctions();
}

$(readyFunctions);
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason why it runs multiple times is simply because you keep binding a `'click'` event to the element(s) with the class `getDogs`! When you bind an event listener with jQuery, *(`$('.getDogs').on('click', 'puppyButton', ...` in this case)* it doesn't overwrite the previous event listener, instead it binds a new listener while keeping the previous ones. In other words, everytime you click a `.getDogs .puppyButton` element, it adds a new `click` listener for each previous listeners you had, that's why the code repeats multiple times!

To correct it, you should unbind your previous listener *(you can do that with [jQuery's .off() event unbinder](https://api.jquery.com/off/))*, i.e:

```
async function getNumber() {
    var $getDogs = $('.getDogs');

    console.log('getNumber ran');

    // unbind (remove) the previous 'click' listener, if any
    $getDogs.off('click.get-number');

    // binds the new onclick listener
    await $getDogs.on('click.get-number', '.puppyButton', function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        $('.dogDisplay').empty();
        console.log("Display emptied");
        dogNumber = $('.puppyNumber').val();
        console.log('dogNumber is: ' + dogNumber);

        arrayAPI();
    });
}
```

Notice that I've added an [event.namespace](https://api.jquery.com/event.namespace/) to the 'click' event, that way you garantee that you're only removing that specific event listener, leaving other 'click' events bound to the `.getDogs` element(s) still operational!

Another option is for you to garantee that you only bind the `onclick` event the first time the code runs.